# Convert string lines from a .ini file to int32

Tags: c#, string, hex, streamwriter, int32

My program creates couple string hex numbers and saves it to a .ini file on my computer. Now I want to convert them to int32. In my .ini file the hex values are listed this way:

- 02E8ECB4
- 02E8ECB5
- 02E8ECE7
- 02E8EC98

and now I want these values in the same .ini file replaced with the new converted values, like:

- 48819380
- 48819381
- 48819431
- 48819352

That is how i save the values:

```
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\values.ini", true))
            {
                foreach (string key in values.Keys)
                {
                    if (values[key] != string.Empty)
                        writer.WriteLine("{1}", key, values[key]);
                }

            }
```

Comment: What is values? How is defined and loaded? Your WriteLine is wrong, There are two arguments but only a placeholder  {1} only for the last argument. But your _question_ lacks the most important thing. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is how to parse each of these strings and create the corresponding int for each of them you could try the following:

```
int val;
if(int.TryParse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, out val))
{
    // The parsing succeeded, so you can continue with the integer you have 
    // now in val. 
}
```

where `str` is the string, for instance the `"02E8ECB4"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ' `int.Parse()` to convert the values from hex to decimal like this:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\values.ini", true))
{
    foreach (string key in values.Keys)
    {
        if (values[key] != string.Empty)
        {
            int hex;
            if(int.TryParse(values[key], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, out hex))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("{1}", key, hex);
            }
            else
            {
                //Replace this line with your error handling code.
                writer.WriteLine("Failed to convert {1}", key, values[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```